# Vue + Vuex using axios asynchrnously yet getters return empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My issue is getters that are returning initial state (`[]`).

in my component I have a `created` method that sets the axios call result into state.

`created() {this.$store.dispatch("SET_STORIES");},`

I have mapGetters in computed:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["GET_STORIES"])
  },
```

And a method to get state:

```
  methods: {
    stories() {
      return this.$store.getters.GET_STORIES;
    }
  }
```

`mounted()` is returning an empty array:

```
  mounted() {
    console.log("stories", this.$store.getters.GET_STORIES);
  },
```

### store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import chunk from "lodash/chunk";
Vue.use(Vuex, VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    stories: [],
    twoChunkStories: []
  },
  getters: {
    GET_STORIES: state => {
      return state.stories;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_STORIES(state, stories) {
      state.stories = stories;
    },
    SET_CHUNKED_STORIES(state, stories) {
      state.twoChunkStories= stories;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    SET_STORIES: async ({ commit }) => {
      const options = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      };
      let { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://api.example.com/get.json",
        options
      );
      if (data.meta.code === 200) {
        let storiesArray = data.data.stories;
        let chunkSize = 2;
        commit("SET_STORIES", storiesArray);
        let chunkedArray = chunk(storiesArray, chunkSize);
        commit("SET_CHUNKED_STORIES", chunkedArray);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How can I make an axios async call that would have state set onload on the earliest lifecycle hook (I thought `created()` was the earliest hook) and be ready to be called out on mounted. I'm obviously doing something wrong asynchronously over the getters, I just don't know exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call your action method of **SET_STORIES** in your component, so the stories in your store will not get updated, first you need to call the action from your Vue component like

```
mounted() {
 this.$store.actions.SET_STORIES
}
```

Also, I think you need to use a different logic here, because you don't know how long does it take to fetch the stories data from your server.

In your component you can create a variable named ***isDataLoaded*** and make it false initially. 
In your component you can conditionally render your list like

```
<div v-if="!isDataLoaded">
  Loading ...
</div>

<div v-if="isDataLoaded">
  ... your list goes here ...
</div>
```

In your *mounted()* method you need to update *isDataLoaded* after the action call like this so your list will show up in the screen

```
async mounted() {
 await this.$store.actions.SET_STORIES
 this.isDataLoaded = true
}
```

Comment: `this.$store.dispatch("SET_STORIES");` is used to call (dispatch) an action.

Comment: I did dispatch it, I wrote it in the question: `created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("SET_STORIES");
  },`

Comment: Moreover, You're doing an async call on mounted, which would make the whole app hang if there is an issue with the server side. But I have to add that it did solve the async issue, yet i'm not sure mounted is the right place to do it..

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize you dispatch it in the begining, and I made a typo it should not be this.$store.actions, instead this.$store.dispatch :) @Daniel. Actually as I looked through the docs, created method is better to use

Comment: You can mark my post as solved if it did solve your problem :)

Comment: It’s not my post ;)

Comment: Haha sorry :) I guess I need to take a break from working